# Как составить регулярное выражение для ссылок на видео YouTube?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь на https://regex101.com/ составить регулярку вида `href="([^"]+?)"`, не получается, опыта мало (Хочу собрать только ссылки видео YouTube). То есть мне не нужны ссылки на плейлисты, каналы, внешние ссылки и прочее.

Мне нужно регуляркой на PHP выбирать только ссылки, имеющие вот такой вид:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjPPSv6ihL8
А все остальные ссылки, например, вот это https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjPPSv6ihL8&list=PLm6bORtbrjJly86OIWyr6a_CCEtaOQCWJ мне не нужно брать.

Вот эта регулярка `href="([^"]+?)"` выбирает все ссылки, а вот эта не работает: `^(?!&list=$)([a-z]{5}[:]{1}[{2}[a-z]{3}[.]{1}[a-z]{7}[.]{1}[a-z]{3}/watch\?v=[a-z]{2}[A-Z]{3}[a-z]{1}[0-9]{1}[a-z]{2}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}([&]{0,1})?([a-z]{0,4})?([=]{0,1})?([A-Z]{0,2})?([a-z]{0,1})?([0-9]{0,1})?([a-z]{0,1})?([A-Z]{0,2})?([a-z]{0,4})?([A-Z]{0,1})?([a-z]{0,2})?([0-9]{0,2})?([A-Z]{0,3})?([a-z]{0,2})?([0-9]{0,1})?([a-z]{0,1})?([_]{0,1})?([A-Z]{0,3})?([a-z]{0,2})?([A-Z]{0,5})?)$/`

Вообще то я составил очень много регулярок, которые не работают) Более лучше я не смог составить, подскажите, пожалуйста.

**UPD**
Нашел вот такую запись:

```html
<?
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-jPBqNw1uJA¶m1=asd';
if (stripos($url, 'youtube.com') !== false) {
    preg_match('#v=([^\&]+)#is', $url, $videoId);
    if (count ($videoId) > 0) {
        //у нас есть id video, ссылка правильная
        // $videoId[1] - ID видео
    }
}
?>
```

Как мне применить это решение для моей регулярки вида `href="([^"]+?)"`?

Comment: Попробуйте так: `href="([^"=]*watch\?v=[^"&]*)[^"]*"`

Comment: Кстати, возможны и такие варианты ссылок:

`https://www.youtube.com/v/5i7_EMQC2IY`
`https://youtu.be/5i7_EMQC2IY`

Comment: Ваша регулярка помогла, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Можно "*привязаться*" к символу `&`, после которого должен стоять или пробел *(т.к. ссылки не могут содержать пробелов, пробельный символ будет означать конец ссылки, и если вся предыдущая часть совпала с шаблоном, то это именно то, что нужно)*, или конец строки:

```
$str = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjPPSv6ihL7
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjPPSv6ihL8&list=PLm6bORtbrjJly86OIWyr6a_CCEtaOQCWJ';

$patt = '~https?://(?:www\.)?youtube\.com[^&\s]+(?=\s|$)~';
preg_match_all($patt, $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

В результате из двух ссылок скрипт выделит первую:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjPPSv6ihL7
```

Comment: Воспользовался регуляркой, которую предложил iskander1220:
href="([^"=]*watch\?v=[^"&]*)[^"]*" – iskander1220
А ваш вариант будет вот так выглядеть ?

href="~https?://(?:www\.)?youtube\.com[^&\s]+(?=\s|$)~"  ?

Comment: @BigStack внутри html-тега будет так: `'~https?://(?:www\.)?youtube\.com[^&\s]+(?=")~'`